# Can a threaded headeset be converted to a threadless headset

Tags: headset

I just want to ask a burning question in my mind. I still ride a bike that uses threaded headsets, I was wondering if I could use the tightening cap of the headset as the base of the whole thing then use spacers and a star nut and top cap to lock everything down?

I of course have tried the adapter systems, and I do not like how it feels, so I was wondering if I could do what I said above.

Thanks guys!!

UPDATE:

My fork is relatively new and has alot of extra steerer tube because I haven't cut it down yet.

Latest update:

So I went to the bike shops around my town and got to buy a shim or whatever they call it. Also bought the star nut and top cap for the bike. I made them do it for me, and it looks quite good now.. Will be posting a pic later when I get home.

Comment: What advantages does a threadless headset offer that you feel the need to switch?  What exactly is the difference in feed between a threaded with an adapter and a real threadless?

Comment: It makes it a whole lot easier to adjust. I already went through alot of adapters for a threadless stem. So that's why I want to try a threadless set-up

Comment: Don't try to clamp anything around a threaded tube. The threads will act as stress risers and the tube will break. There used to be a threaded headset design where the stem was held in place with clamp instead of expander bolt, there were accidents and the design hasn't been used since 1970s.

Comment: @ojs even if I use a shim? I know some people who have done this and they have went well as far as I know.

Comment: I don't see how a shim would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would attempt to use a threaded headset as a threadless headset - other than trying to save on something which you can't.

The stem and top-cap assembly of a threadless headset are integral to securing the fork into the frame. Whereas a threaded headset secures the to the fork using a large nut.

There is nothing to stop you buying retro one inch fork, threadless headset and stem. That would be the safest way to do it.

Comment: What I meant was, I would use the large nut as you would say it to preload the bearings of the fork and headset. Then I would use the stem and spacers, and lock it all down with the star nut and top cap of a threadless set-up

Comment: No. You would have to over thread the fork to leave about 2.5inch of threaded steerer tube sticking out of the top. Then you would be fixing a stem onto a threaded surface. In my opinion not safe. 
Do it properly.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry.. My steerer tube has alot of extra tibe. You see it's kinda new so that's what made me think of trying this.

Answer (score 0):

With some luck, it may be possible. Chris King sells conversion kits their heasets, they might work with other brands too and cost about the same as a good headset from some other brand. When threaded headsets were still common, there used to be aftermarket conversion kits for other brands, too.

Of course you will need a new fork.